# Adapter is not updating after notify data set is being called

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a list in fragment I am setting it in RecyclerView. There is a button, and on its click I am passing a callback to the Fragment. Now fragment is opening another View which is a activity presented as Dialog, it takes different inputs from user and finally on submit button click, it throws back some sort of data/Model.

Now I get that data in onActivityResult Method of the Fragment, and after changing and replacing the modified data from user into the list I am calling notifyDataSetChanged on the Adapter. but the data is not getting changed. here is I am doing it.

```
  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
  {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == DialogChangeStore.RC_DIALOG_CHANGE_STORE) {

        if (data != null) {

            if (data.hasExtra(DialogChangeStore.KEY_USER_SELECTED_STORE)) {
                PreferredStoreServiceModel model = data.getParcelableExtra(DialogChangeStore.KEY_USER_SELECTED_STORE);
                int position = data.getIntExtra(DialogChangeStore.KEY_CLICKED_GROUP_POSITION, -1);

                if (position == -1) {
                    return;
                }


                if (model != null) {


                    ArrayList<TreeDataModel> mTempList = new ArrayList<>();

                    mTempList.addAll(treeAdapter.getUserList());

                    TreeDataModel modelToBeReplaced = mTempList.get(position);

                    TreeDataModel treeDataModel = new TreeDataModel();

                    treeDataModel.setId(model.getId());
                    treeDataModel.setName(model.getFriendlyName());
                    treeDataModel.setmPreferredStoreServiceModel(model);
                    treeDataModel.setSelected(modelToBeReplaced.isSelected());
                    treeDataModel.setExpanded(modelToBeReplaced.isExpanded());
                    treeDataModel.setHeader(true);
                    treeDataModel.setIndexNumber(modelToBeReplaced.getIndexNumber());


                    mTempList.remove(position);
                    mTempList.add(position,treeDataModel);

                    treeAdapter.getUserList().clear();

                    treeAdapter.setUserList(mTempList);

                    treeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                    selectedChangedStore = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is not working when I do debuging I can see that the data is changed. this method **treeAdapter.getUserList()** returns the list, and it shows me the updated list. But its not actually working for me.

Can you please tell me what could be a problem? I am doing same type of manipulation from other sides/Areas/ using alert dailog, but there I can see list is getting update. The code is relatively same as I shared above.

> Please suggest me what i wrong and what could be a problem. I know it
>   is simple thing to update list and notifyDatasetChanged, but it is not
>   working at the moment. ...

Answer (score 0):

to remove use:

```
 mTempList.remove(position);
 mTempList.add(position,treeDataModel);
 treeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

to add use:

```
 mTempList.set(position,treeDataModel);
 treeAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
```